# Load Category in Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, categories

I have a category that I'm trying to load via a plugin. Looking at the categories service I see there is a function called "getCategoryById" but I don't know what the ID is so instead I'm loading the category group thinking that the ID provided there is what I need, apparently it is not.

Kinda of stumped on this one. Any advice?

Thanks,

Comment: Hey Matt - what infomormation do you have about the category? Name, level, slug?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are searching by, you can use something similar to this. You can see the properties you can search by [in the documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.categories).

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);
$criteria->group = 'CategoryGroupName';
$criteria->title = 'CategoryTitle';
$criteria->limit = 1;

$category = $criteria->find();
```

Comment: Doesn't **craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);** technically load all categories? If so I want to avoid the overhead.

Comment: Nope! It loads an element criteria model of type Category. That simply allows you to query against Category properties like group, title, level, etc. ([source](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/ElementsService.php#L33))

Comment: Oh ok. Cool. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Question: How would I get only the children of a given category? What I mean is... I have a list of countries and under them their states/provinces. Is it possible to do something like **$criteria->children = 1**? I've tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: You can limit the search to what [`level`](https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.categories#level) the category is. So if you know you just want categories of the second level (states/provinces), you can add `$criteria->level = 2` before you run `find()`

Comment: I've done that but I also get the states/provinces from other countries. I assume that **$criteria->level = 2** gets all level 2 items regardless of the parent. At least that has been my experience.

Comment: That's correct. You can limit your search even more if you have the country you want the states from by adding `$criteria->descendantOf = $country`

Comment: Oh ok. It seems to me then that I have to first get the country, then use that data to get the descendantOf. Is there a way to do this all in one shot or do I need to get country then use that result on a second query?

Comment: Yeah, you will need to first get the parent category, then get the children in two separate finds. If you are going to be running these steps frequently, I highly recommend cacheing the process. You can see a simple cache example in [this service](https://github.com/aberkie/craft-summit-api/blob/master/disney/services/Disney_InterestService.php) I made for the Craft CMS summit.

Comment: No problem! If this is working for you, can you select the answer as the correct answer so we can close out your question?

Comment: Not really sure how to do that, but I marked it as userful